# Mat Datepicker validation on no selection

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I am working with Angular 7 application. In which we have used angular material for user design.

```html
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>My Date</mat-label>
        <input name="myDate" placeholder="My Date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" required [(ngModel)]="modalPresentation.myDate" (focus)="picker.open()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error *ngIf="validationUtil.hasError(form.controls.myDate, 'required')">This field is required.</mat-error>  
    </mat-form-field>
```

The covent de working fine when the input text field touched without selecting the date from the picker. But we want validation when the date picker is opened by the user but not selected any date and clicked outside without selecting any date. So I want to show red-bordered on the input text field on the date.i

I want the close event when date picker get closed without any date selection.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: There is no issue in the current code, but I want new validation on the date picker click and not selecting the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mat-datepicker has closed event emitter which will emit event when datepicker has been closed. use that to trigger mat-datepicker form control validation manually.

**Try this:**

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>My Date</mat-label>
        <input  name="myDate" placeholder="My Date" #ref="ngModel" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [required]="true" [(ngModel)]="modalPresentation" (focus)="picker.open()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle  matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker (closed)="onClosed(ref)" #picker></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error *ngIf="ref.touched && ref.invalid">This field is required.</mat-error>   
 </mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

```
onClosed(formControl){
    formControl.control.markAsTouched();
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b1auah)